# Using Maven artifacts from the local maven repository in Gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm trying to figure out how to use a library I made (Maven project) in my Android application. I've tried this in my project's build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

And then this in my app's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'nl.han.asd.project.client:commonclient:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

This is the artifact's definition:

```
<groupId>nl.han.asd.project.client</groupId>
<artifactId>commonclient</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

But still Gradle can't resolve the dependency.

Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I should clarify the artifact is present in my %MAVEN_HOME% directory.

Comment: Is section "repositories" definition for gradle plugins or project dependencies? Also check https://discuss.gradle.org/t/mavenlocal-how-does-gradle-resolve-the-directory-of-the-local-maven-repository/4407